# Dynamically change data in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, object

I have an array

```
Array [
  "2022-03-25",
  "2022-03-10",
  "2022-03-24",
  "2022-03-31",
  "2022-03-12",
  "2022-03-23",
  "2022-03-22",
  "2022-03-16",
  "2022-03-11",
  "2022-03-26",
]
```

And I have the data of objects:

```
 Object {
  "2022-03-10": Object {
    "marked": true,
  },
  "2022-03-11": Object {
    "marked": true,
  },
  "2022-03-12": Object {
    "marked": true,
  },
  "2022-03-16": Object {
    "marked": true,
  },
  "2022-03-18": Object {
    "marked": true,
  },
  "2022-03-22": Object {
    "marked": true,
  },
  "2022-03-23": Object {
    "marked": true,
  },
  "2022-03-24": Object {
    "marked": true,
  },
  "2022-03-25": Object {
    "marked": true,
  },
  "2022-03-26": Object {
    "marked": true,
  },
  "2022-03-27": Object {
    "marked": true,
  },
  "2022-03-31": Object {
    "marked": true,
  },
}
```

In the objects, theres is a date "2022-03-27", however, it is not in the array. What I would like to do is, if the date is not in the ARRAY, I would like to remove it from the object, or mark it as false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm taking all the keys of your object, then iterating over the collection and updating the `marked` property according to whether the date is included in the Array.
Assumption: The `objects` Object is being used to track state and so is intended to be mutable.

```js
let dates = [ "2022-03-25", "2022-03-10", "2022-03-24", "2022-03-31", "2022-03-12",
              "2022-03-23", "2022-03-22", "2022-03-16", "2022-03-11", "2022-03-26" ]
let objects = { "2022-03-10": { marked: true }, "2022-03-11": { marked: true },
                "2022-03-12": { marked: true }, "2022-03-16": { marked: true },
                "2022-03-18": { marked: true }, "2022-03-22": { marked: true },
                "2022-03-23": { marked: true }, "2022-03-24": { marked: true },
                "2022-03-25": { marked: true }, "2022-03-26": { marked: true },
                "2022-03-27": { marked: true }, "2022-03-31": { marked: true }
}
keySet = Object.keys(objects)
keySet.forEach( key => objects[ key ].marked = dates.includes(key) )
console.log(objects)
```

In order to avoid updating objects that  have no meaningful change, you could do this instead:

```
Object.keys(objects).filter(date => !dates.includes(date)).map( date =>  objects[ date ].marked = false )
console.log(objects)
```

Comment: This was simple and perfect, thank you very much

Comment: Thanks.  Probably better to use `forEach` rather than `map` in the 2nd version.  Misuse of `map`.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid mutating the original object you can use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) passing the filtered [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of the original. Here simply using [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and testing using [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
const array = ["2022-03-25", "2022-03-10", "2022-03-24", "2022-03-31", "2022-03-12", "2022-03-23", "2022-03-22", "2022-03-16", "2022-03-11", "2022-03-26",];
const object = { "2022-03-10": { "marked": true, }, "2022-03-11": { "marked": true, }, "2022-03-12": { "marked": true, }, "2022-03-16": { "marked": true, }, "2022-03-18": { "marked": true, }, "2022-03-22": { "marked": true, }, "2022-03-23": { "marked": true, }, "2022-03-24": { "marked": true, }, "2022-03-25": { "marked": true, }, "2022-03-26": { "marked": true, }, "2022-03-27": { "marked": true, }, "2022-03-31": { "marked": true, }, };

const filteredObject = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(object)
    .filter(([key]) => array.includes(key))
);

console.log(filteredObject);
```

To instead toggle the `marked` properties of each nested object you can use a similar method, but instead of `filter()` you can [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the original `Object.entries` here using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to clone each nested object and overwrite the `marked` property with the result of the same `includes()` call as the previous example.

```js
const array = ["2022-03-25", "2022-03-10", "2022-03-24", "2022-03-31", "2022-03-12", "2022-03-23", "2022-03-22", "2022-03-16", "2022-03-11", "2022-03-26",];
const object = { "2022-03-10": { "marked": true, }, "2022-03-11": { "marked": true, }, "2022-03-12": { "marked": true, }, "2022-03-16": { "marked": true, }, "2022-03-18": { "marked": true, }, "2022-03-22": { "marked": true, }, "2022-03-23": { "marked": true, }, "2022-03-24": { "marked": true, }, "2022-03-25": { "marked": true, }, "2022-03-26": { "marked": true, }, "2022-03-27": { "marked": true, }, "2022-03-31": { "marked": true, }, };

const markedObject = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(object)
    .map(([key, value]) => [key, { ...value, marked: array.includes(key) }])
);

console.log(markedObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over object keys, find if the key exists in the array, delete it from the object if not found:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    if (arr.includes(key) === false) {
        delete obj[key];
    }
});
```

Comment: Note to the editor: Array.map is supposed to transform the array into another array and you're interested in return value. It is a bad choice in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Array.prototype.includes()` method.  Just extract the value from your object and use a conditional statement.

```
if array.includes(yourObjectDate) {
return true
} else {
return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (const property in object) {
  array.find(date => object[property].marked = date === property);
}
```

Comment: Actually that isn't true. I was marking true instead of false https://jsfiddle.net/9fbrvj5a . updated response above.

Comment: You probably want to avoid patterns like this.  You're modifying every element of `object` once for every element of `array`.  This is O(n^2) instead of O(n), and write operations tend to be significantly more expensive than read operations.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to remove the object whose date is not in `dates`:

```js
let dates = [ "2022-03-25", "2022-03-10", "2022-03-24", "2022-03-31", "2022-03-12", "2022-03-23", "2022-03-22", "2022-03-16", "2022-03-11", "2022-03-26" ];
let objects = { "2022-03-10": { marked: true }, "2022-03-11": { marked: true }, "2022-03-12": { marked: true }, "2022-03-16": { marked: true }, "2022-03-18": { marked: true }, "2022-03-22": { marked: true }, "2022-03-23": { marked: true }, "2022-03-24": { marked: true }, "2022-03-25": { marked: true }, "2022-03-26": { marked: true }, "2022-03-27": { marked: true }, "2022-03-31": { marked: true } };

Object.keys(objects).forEach(
    key => dates.includes(key) || delete objects[key]
); 

console.log(objects)
```